# The cost of an algorithm

Tags: optimization

Please tell me what is the correct formula for calculating the cost of an algorithm? I used this: number of calculated functions + 4 * number of calculated function gradients + 8 * number of calculated Hessian matrices of the function. I use this formula to calculate the cost of Newton's method of finding the minimum of a function.

Update: I'm multiplying the number of gradients by 4 since it's a vector consisting of the derivative of a function with respect to coordinates (I'm considering a plane, meaning (x,y) coordinates). I multiply the number of Hessian matrices by 8, since for it we need second derivatives.

For a better understanding of my question, I will attach part of the code.

```
struct hesse
{
    double a, b, c, d;
    void init(point A)
    {
        count_h += 1;
        a = kvadrdxx(A);
        d = kvadrdyy(A);
        b = kvadrdxy(A);
        c = kvadrdxy(A);
    }
    void inverse()
    {
        double det = (a * d - b * c);
        if (det != 0)
        {
            a = a / det;
            b = b / det;
            c = c / det;
            d = d / det;
            std::swap(a, d);
            c = -c;
            b = -b;
        }
    }
    void pol()
    {
        double nu = 0;
        while (a <= 0 || (a * d - b * c) <= 0)
        {
            nu = nu + 0.1;
            a = a + nu;
            d = d + nu;
        }
    }
    point operator*(point A)
    {
        point p(0, 0);
        p.x = a * A.x + b * A.y;
        p.y = c * A.x + d * A.y;
        return p;
    }
};

point newton(point& X0, double e)
{
    point pk(0, 0);
    point X = X0;
    point gr1(kvadrdx(X0), kvadrdy(X0));
    double norm_antigr = my_norm(gr1);
    hesse h;
    while (norm_antigr > e)
    {
        count_it += 1;
        out.push_back(X);
        h.init(X);
        h.pol();
        h.inverse();
        pk = (h * gr1) * (-1);
        X = X + pk;
        point gr(kvadrdx(X), kvadrdy(X));
        gr1 = gr;
        norm_antigr = my_norm(gr1);
    }
    out.push_back(X);
    return X;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! We need you to edit your question to please clarify: What is the algorithm you are talking about? What do you mean by cost of that algorithm? How do you arrive at your answer? Use multiple paragraphs so they become clearer. Thank you.

Comment: I’ve implemented lots of algorithms without any function gradients or hessians. So please tell us exactly what algorithms you are talking about.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and for added details, Mark. But your question is not answerable as it stands. Please follow my instructions and gnasher's instructions so you are able to receive an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the cost of an algorithm, measure its execution time in seconds. Then you either take the cost of a new computer, calculate for how many seconds it runs your algorithm during its life, adding cost for the space where it lives and electricity. Or you ask a cloud service provider what it costs to rent their computers per hour, and calculate the cost from there.

If by “cost” you mean something other than dollars, pound, euros, yen or yuan, please clarify.